# My Laravel Routes is not working on CentOS

Tags: laravel, centos

I just made a simple laravel application in CentOS running in apache server. The thing is I always gets an error:

> "Not Found" when redirecting to other pages.

How do I fix this ? I'am completely new on using CentOS and apache server.

**Note:** It is working fine with Windows and xampp.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: add little bit of code so that i can help

Comment: i just added my .htaccess file

Comment: Please Share the Screen Shot of the project structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that route with index.php? like yourdomain.com/index.php/route-url and check if it works. If your homepage works and other pages do not, then your rewrite rule is no set.

- Do

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite on
```

your server terminal and then restart apache

- In Apache virtual host  section add

```
AllowOverride all
```

And in your laravel's .htaccess add this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: yes my homepage works but other pages do not. Already set mod_rewrite to "on" and "AllowOverride" all. However when I do "php artisan serve" it works perfectly even on CentOS

Comment: Can you do phpinfo() in index.php for once and check if mod rewrites shows as enabled?

Comment: what exactly should I suppose to see ? I'm so sorry I'm totally new to this

Comment: you can check if mod_rewrites is mentioned in enabled modules for php

Comment: did you add AllowOverride All to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf?

Comment: Check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Thank you redoing all the steps altogether solved the problem !

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you don't have Apache set up to properly rewrite your route and hand it to the index.php file.  Have a look at the Apache section near the bottom of [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation) page and ensure that your redirects mirror what this page lays out.

Comment: Can you paste the Apache config into this thread, and maybe your .env as well?

Comment: I'm following apache configuration from laravel documentation guide